# Sci-fi anthology for kids of alien stories - aliens lure humans into a garbage disposal and put them in zoos

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, childrens-novel

One of the stories was about the aliens building an invisible structure and they play music that calls all the humans to it. The main character is pulled away from it and is angry even though he knows it's a garbage disposal. He's put into a prison with invisible furniture with a few other young prisoners.

Another one is there's a zoo and humans are on display.

Soft cover, American, read it around 2002-2005, the cover was gray I think? May have had an alien or a spaceship on it. No interior illustrations. So it may have been a young adult novel?

Answer (score 5):

This may be *[Aliens: Terrifying Extraterrestrial Tales](https://books.google.com/books?id=o4nr_YWggj4C)* by Don Wulfsson. "The Dastasian Invasion" was the story with them building the "garbage disposals", as mentioned in the answers to [Looking for a story about aliens building invisible structures on earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/92478/23243) and [Collection of youth short stories about aliens 1990-1994ish](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/collection-of-youth-short-stories-about-aliens-1990-1994ish).

It's also the story with the humans as zoo exhibits, although another story in the collection has humans visiting a zoo with an alien, "An Eye for an Eye".

There seem to have been two covers, neither of which quite match your memory:

[image: Cyclops cover] [image: Goblin cover]

Comment: If this is the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.